# How to create dynamic tablelayout with unknown count of rows and cols?

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout, inflate

I'd like to create dynamic tablelayout. I've got these nodes (beause each node has seperate style):

- header row
- header cell
- odd row
- odd row cell
- even row
- even row cell
  like this:

  ```
   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/header_row"
       style="@style/HeaderRow"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/header_tv"
           style="@style/HeaderText"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/bodyrow_odd"
       style="@style/BodyRowOdd"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/body_tv_odd"
           style="@style/BodyTextOdd"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/bodyrow_even"
       style="@style/BodyRowEven"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/body_tv_even"
           style="@style/BodyTextEven"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </TableRow>
  ```

if I'd like to create dynamic interface by inflating each node, i have to have each node in seperate xml?`

Comment: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/

Comment: @Bhavin I really want to have styles in styles.xml not *.java.

Answer (score -1):

MainActivity.class

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
init();
}

public void init() {
TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tbrow0.addView(tv0);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText(" Product ");
tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tbrow0.addView(tv1);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText(" Unit Price ");
tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tbrow0.addView(tv2);
TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
tv3.setText(" Stock Remaining ");
tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tbrow0.addView(tv3);
// Apply here your HeaderRow style.
tbrow0.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
stk.addView(tbrow0);
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
t1v.setText("" + i);
t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(t1v);
TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
t2v.setText("Product " + i);
t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(t2v);
TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
t3v.setText("Rs." + i);
t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(t3v);
TextView t4v = new TextView(this);
t4v.setText("" + i * 15 / 32 * 10);
t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tbrow.addView(t4v);
if (i % 2 == 0) {
// Apply here your BodyRowEven style.
tbrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
} else {
// Apply here your BodyRowOdd style.
tbrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
}
stk.addView(tbrow);
}
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#ffffff">

<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/table_main"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```